# Using geocomplete in Meteor App

Tags: jquery, google-maps, meteor, meteor-blaze, geocomplete

Please I quickly need a fix to this. I have been trying to add geocomplete to my Meteor js app but keeps getting errors. I have installed geocomplete via NPM into the Meteor app. How do I use it from there? Or is there any other Meteor package that has implemented this because I have none. I have tried following this implementation http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/form.html but could not get it to work.

This is the UI code

```
<template name="geos">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="geocomplete" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type in an address" value="Lekki Phase" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCWz0jrRG2GoQ&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
</template>
```

NPM install

```
C:\Programs\contract\schoolapps>npm install geocomplete
npm WARN deprecated uglifyjs@2.4.11: uglifyjs is deprecated - use uglify-js instead.
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g
schoolapps@ C:\Programs\contract\schoolapps
`-- geocomplete@1.7.0
  +-- docco@0.6.3
  | +-- commander@2.9.0
  | | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1
  | +-- fs-extra@3.0.1
  | | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
  | | +-- jsonfile@3.0.0
  | | | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11  deduped
  | | `-- universalify@0.1.0
  | +-- highlight.js@9.11.0
  | +-- marked@0.3.6
  | `-- underscore@1.8.3
  `-- uglifyjs@2.4.11
```

This is the onrendered function

```
Template.SchoolContactLayout.rendered = function () {
    $(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
        });
     });
}
```

I got this error on the console

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:930 TypeError: $(...).geocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (schoolcontact.js:25)
    at fire (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:3201)
    at Object.self.add [as done] (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:3247)
    at jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:3481)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:2921)
    at jQuery (jquery.js?hash=c57b3cf…:131)
    at Template.SchoolContactLayout.rendered (schoolcontact.js:2)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3398
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3744)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3394)
```

what do i do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because its not able to find the dom and its considering it as a meteor function. You should call the method once the dom is rendered and use a 'this' keyword before to point to template instance in which the dom exists for jquery to consider it.

```
Template.SchoolContactLayout.onRendered(function(){
  // we're using the template instance scoped jQuery

this.$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({

      map: ".map_canvas",
      details: "form",
      types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
  });
});
```

Confirm back if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Chetan. I have changed it based on your suggestion and I'm getting this error again:  ```TypeError: this.$ is not a function
   out.rendered (schoolcontact.js:13)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3398
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3744)
    at fireCallbacks (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3394)```

Comment: are you able to access the dom using jquery inside the template? Check running some simple jquery like get the value of textbox and print on console.. This will confirm if its jquery which is not working or only the geocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works

```
Template.SchoolContactLayout.onCeated(function () {
          $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
        });
     });
```

Comment: `$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
           details: "form",
           types: ["geocode", "establishment"],
         });` THis is what i used because i don't want to display the map. It worked thisway. The concern then was the Google maps api. Thanks.